# VBScript accepts "2.50+" and "2.50-" as valid numeric types?

Tags: vbscript, types, isnumeric

I have a condition in my code similar to:

```
If not IsNumeric(x) Then ...
End If
```

when `x = "2.50+` or `x = "2.50-` or any other valid number with '+' or '-' tacked on to the end, IsNumeric(x) returns True!

So both examples of x are valid numeric types for VBScript, but I can't find anything online that documents or suggests this. Why does VBScript allow this, and what would it be used for?

Comment: Apparently putting the plus/minus sign at the end is a [valid way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/42964) to format a number, so `isnumeric` recognizes it (so do `val`/`cdbl`).

Comment: Accountants think that is entirely valid.  They also like (2.50) to make it not so obvious that money was lost.  And $2.50.  And 2.50R.  Etcetera, VScript's glass is always half-full.

Comment: ISNumeric in the VBA spec checks the value type is numeric (except for date). In practise it probably means it does a CInt, CLng, or CDbl and see if any are successful. This is the overall rules for Let Coercion from VBA Language Spec (VBS 99.99% compliant in the features it implements) -

Comment: *The formats accepted or produced when coercing number, currency and date values to or from String respects host-defined regional settings. Excess whitespace is ignored at the beginning or end of the value or when inserted before or after date/time separator characters such as "/" and ":", sign characters such as "+", "-" and the scientific notation character "E".* (5.5.1.2.4   Let-coercion to and from String) There is a page of more detailed rules. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the links to the documentation! @Noodles